# Implementation of rectangular KDE in R

Tags: r, kernel-density

I wonder how the KDE function in R is implemented, because I saw some weird stuff in my plots.

dates5.csv is nothing more than:

```
  day
2013-01-02
2013-03-01
```

i.e. two dates. Now I read in the data, compute rectangular KDE out of if, and get the plot below:

```
  data <- read.csv("dates5.csv", header=T)
  days <- data$day

  daysPosix <- as.POSIXct(days, tz="Europe/Zurich")

# compute density
  ds <- density(as.numeric(daysPosix), 
                bw = 3600 * 24 * 7,
                kernel = "rectangular",
                cut = 3)
  plot(ds, xaxt ="n", xlab="", ylab="",  ylim = c(0,max(ds$y)),
         main = "Temporal density (uniform kernel,
                     bandwidth = 7 days)")

    points(x = as.numeric(daysPosix),
           y=rep(0, length(daysPosix)),
           pch="|",
           col="#00000080")
    times.seq <- seq(daysPosix[1],
                     daysPosix[length(daysPosix)],
                     by = "weeks")
    labels = strftime(times.seq, "%d.%m.%y")
    axis(1,times.seq,labels)
```

[image]

The tick marks at the x axis are separated by *weeks*. At the first sight, the plot makes sense, two rectancular shapes are built on top of the two points. ***Still, there are two things which I don't understand:*** Why is the approximate range of each "shape" a bit more than 3 weeks long, and not as expected 7 days (since this is the bandwidth?)? And why do the shapes have *steep* "cliffs" on both sides but not vertical ones?

Comment: The docs note that: `The kernels are scaled such that this is the standard deviation of the smoothing kernel.` So `bw = 3600*24*7/(2*qnorm(0.975))` appears to give one-week wide shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?density` notes that:

> > `bw` the smoothing bandwidth to be used. 
> >       The kernels are scaled such that this is the standard deviation of the smoothing kernel.

So `bw = 3600*24*7/sqrt(12)` appears to give one-week wide shapes. In other words, you need to "de-scale" your bandwith, so that when it is scaled by `density` you get what you want. You can alternatively set `adjust = 1/sqrt(12)`.

To make to shapes have vertical drop-offs, increase `n` to improve the computational resolution, eg `n = 2^15`.

So change your `density` call to:

```
  ds <- density(as.numeric(daysPosix), 
                bw = 3600 * 24 * 7 / sqrt(12),
                kernel = "rectangular",
                cut = 3, n=2^15)
```

And checking the width of the shapes:

```
which(abs(diff(ds$y))>max(ds$y)/2) # approximate locations of the edges
[1]  1197  4469 28299 31571
(ds$x[4469]-ds$x[1197])/(3600*24*7)
[1] 1.00034
```

Comment: OK, I somehow understand the part with `bw = 3600*24*7/(2*qnorm(0.975))`, dividing by 95% of the standard normal distribution. But wouldn't dividing by `sqrt(12)` give more appropriate results because we use a uniform kernel? And the other thing is - I tried setting `adjust = 1/(2*qnorm(0.975))` without setting `bw` at all, i.e. it uses the default setting `bw = "nrd0"`.. But still, from looking at the plot, I get almost exactly the same results as when specifying `bw = 3600 * 24 * 14 / (2*qnorm(0.975))`, i.e. using a 14 days bandwidth. Does this mean that by default, "nrd0" ...

Comment: arrives at a bandwidth of 14 days with the data I have? I checked it with different temporal distributions though and always got something very similar.

Comment: And I still didn't fully understand why one divides by 95% of the standard normal distribution - this encompasses *two* standard deviations and not just one, right?

Comment: @wnstnsmth Looking more carefully at the widths of the shapes, using `qnorm` gives around 6.19 days, while the `sqrt` method gives almost exactly 7 days. I'll change the answer. By setting the `adjust` parameter I meant to adjust your original bandwidth.

Comment: I know that using `adjust` results in a final bandwidth of `adjust*bw`, but the weird thing is that if I don't even specify a `bw` on my own I still get very similar or the same results as when I explicitly choose a `bw` of 14 days... any explanations for that?

Comment: @wnstnsmth Coincidence I think. See `?bw.nrd0` - the equation is: `0.9*min(sd(daysPosix),IQR(daysPosix))/1.34*(length(daysPosix)^(-1/5))` which gives `16.95625` when divided through to give days